# linq + groupby - add fields in select query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

question : can we made groupby to multiple fields in LINQ 
Currently - i have linq something like this

```
q = q.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
     .Select(g => new View
                  {
                      Id = g.Key,
                      ENAME= string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.CaseApprover).ToList())
                  });
```

i wanted to group by with multiple fields something like

```
q = q.GroupBy(c => c.Id, c.name,c.age,c.dob)
```

also how to put them in select query? such that i will get the newly added fields in select query also.

Comment: Start with `q.GroupBy(c => new { c.Id, c.name,c.age,c.dob } )`

Comment: but if i am using this code i am getting error on Id = g.Key "cannot convert anonymoustype#1 to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
q = q.GroupBy(c => new { c.Id, c.name,c.age,c.dob })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key.Id,
        ENAME= string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.CaseApprover).ToList()),
        Name = g.Key.name,
        Age = g.Key.age,
        Dob = g.Key.dob,
    });
```

This will return an anonymous type, if you want these fields in your `View` class, just add them.