# groupby to multiple fields in LINQ Currently - i have linq something like this

Tags: entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linq + groupby - add fields in select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636446/linq-groupby-add-fields-in-select-query)

I  wanted to group by with multiple fields something like q = q.GroupBy(c => c.Id, c.name,c.age,c.dob)

also how to put them in select query ?? such that i will get the newly added fields in select query also.

```
q = q.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
                       .Select(g => new View
                       {
                           Id = g.Key,
                           ENAME= string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.CaseApprover).ToList())
                       });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "newly added fields"?

Answer (score 0):

To group by multiple fields you do this:

```
var query = q.GroupBy(c => new { c.Id, c.name, c.age, c.dob });
```

You'll have to clarify the second part of your question (as per my comment above) if you want the answer to the rest.

Comment: second part of my question is - say suppose i have added c.name , c.age in Groupby statement so when i am using the same in select statement it's throwing error